# Retrieve JSON and display it in table layout (Android)

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I'm a newbie in Android, and as part of a project I need to access a website and retrieve the JSON information on there and then display it. It has to be done asynchronous (using AsyncTask). I somewhat grasp the idea of retrieving the data, but how to process the JSON object itself, and to put certain elements of the object into certain areas of the display (I use a table layout with textviews, although I know a listview would be better, I want it to get to work this way and then move forward).

This is how the JSON looks like on the webpage:

```
    {"shopLocation":"web","shopName":"ABC",
    "items":[{"id":1,"item":"Item1","price":"23.90"},
    {"id":2,"item":"Item2","price":"18.36"},
    {"id":3,"item":"Item3","price":"53.90"}]}
```

This is the layout

```
           <Table Layout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Location:"/>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:id="@+id/shopLocationText"
                  android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:text="Shop Name:"/>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:id="@+id/shopNameText"
                  android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </TableRow>        
    <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="0px"
                  android:text="Item:"
                  android:textSize="25dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="0px"
                  android:text="Price"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="0px"
                  android:id="@+id/ID1Text"
                  android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="0px"
                  android:id="@+id/item1Text"
                  android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="0px"
                  android:id="@+id/price1Text"
                  android:layout_weight="1"/>
      </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

How do I retrieve the JSON data from the url (I'd rather not post the actual url) specifically with AsyncTask, then after I do that, how do I dissassemble the data and connect it to it's according textviews? (I cut off some of the layout xml file).

I'm really in a predicament any and all help would be absolutely great!

Comment: There are many tutorials on google on how to parse json and show it in a listview or in your case a table. If you are a newbee then you should read tutorials

Comment: I've read and seen many of them, and yet I cannot make a functional app, they always crash

Comment: An app Crash have a reason which you will find in LOGCAT. Please go through basic android tutorials first